# how to set webbrowser control document body size according to webbrowser control size

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

my webbrowser control height and width is minimum as compare to page that i load in to webbrowser control thats why page not completely show in my webbrowser control. i want to show full page in give height width of webbrowser control. any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to decode.  WebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle gives the size of the loaded document.  You have to add the size of the scrollbar, use the SystemInformation class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are saying but from assumption it sounds like you want to know how to make the webBrowser control wider to be able to see the web page.

If you want to just show scroll bars just make sure the control has the `ScrollBarsEnabled` flag set to true.